# PostgreSQL, checking date relative to "today"

Tags: sql, postgresql

Was wondering if someone could assist with some Postgres. I have a table which has a column called `mydate` which is a postgres date type. I want to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE mydate > [Today-1year]
```

I've never used Postgres before and I'm sure I just need to know the name of some functions- I'll gladly look up the reference myself. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: For the record, the documentation is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-datetime.html) -- it takes a little getting used to, but it's extremely comprehensive.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

```
select * from mytable where mydate > now() - interval '1 year';
```

If you only care about the date and not the time, substitute `current_date` for `now()`

```
select * from mytable where mydate > current_date - interval '1 year';
```

Comment: Note that `now()` is a timestamp, so this range will also only include part of the day from exactly a year ago and part of the day today. If you want to filter on full days, cast `now()::date` as Alex Howansky suggested.

Comment: @tokenizer_fsj of use `current_date` instead of `now()`

Comment: `current_date()` is not working for me (postgres 12.1), but `now()::date` is.

Comment: @niid it’s `current_date` without the brackets. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Comment: () are called parenthesis. brackets are []. curly braces {}

Comment: @oligofren if you look up “parenthesis” in the dictionary, one of the definitions is `a pair of round brackets ( ) used to mark off a parenthetical word or phrase.` In no definition is a pair of empty round brackets a “parenthesis”. https://g.co/kgs/78V8pt4

Comment: @PaulTomblin Actually, when googling "brackets parentheses braces" you'll see the usage in maths match exactly what I was stating (all the top ten hits actually), but I learned something new: it's really about American English vs British English. In AE they are referred to as parenthesis, whereas in BE it's brackets. Also: all the odd shapes are variations of brackets: round, angled, boxed, curly. Still, I think you'll see that the most common usage is exactly my listing, but calling `()` brackets is clearly correct in the Queen's (now King's) English :)

Answer (score 80):

I think this will do it:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE mydate > now()::date - 365;
```

Comment: Note that unlike `interval '1 year'`, this will not respect leap years.  That may not be a concern of yours, but if it is, use my answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

`now()` returns a timestamp, so after subtracting `'1 day'`, you end up with a timestamp that likely will filter out part of the day that you are interested in querying. Most people want to filter on a single full day, and so using `now()::date` or `CURRENT_DATE` is necessary.

Answer (score 9):

This should give you the current date minus 1 year:

```
select now() - interval '1 year';
```

Answer (score 8):

You could also check using the `age()` function

`select * from mytable where age( mydate, now() ) > '1 year';`

`age()` wil return an interval.

For example `age( '2015-09-22', now() )` will return `-1 years -7 days -10:56:18.274131`

See [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: I'm told `age()` is a PostgreSQL-only function (2018-10-05)

Comment: As id the question @loxaxs